# Add meta data in head from theme

Tags: functions, theme-development

I want to add a meta data in the head of my website.

I have a post type with custom template : `single-custom.php`

In this template, I want to add this meta : `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` considering some variable.

I collect number of post related to the current post... I use :

```
// if less than 6 related posts, add meta
if (count($posts) < 6) {
      add_action( 'wp_head', 'noindex_meta' );
}
```

And in my *functions.php* :

```
// add noindex meta to head
function noindex_meta() {
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">';
}
```

But it doesn't work, it works if I call `add_action(...)` in my *functions.php*, but not in theme template.

Is it possible ?

Comment: (Ignore my previous comment. But once again,) in that theme template, if you want to hook `noindex_meta()` to `wp_head`, you should do it before `get_header()` call in the template file. See [this](https://pastebin.com/yWhCNZmL).

Comment: I put the code before `get_header()` in my template page, it works perfectly. Thanks for the advice.